# Exit the python function in case of error, and need to pass the exit value to batch file

Tags: python

```
if ("FATAL_ERROR" == level):
send_mail()
sys.exit()
```

Can anyone help with the above Exit function, as we have to pass the exit value to the batch file once it receives **error**?

send mail is the function written in the script, which send the mail to the user when a fatal error occurs...System.error is typing mistake... it's actually sys.exit()...i want whenever "fatal error occurs" it come out and pass the exit value to the batch file...we tried we the sys.exit() but it's not working...pls suggest with some more functions

Comment: Where are the functions `send_mail()` and `System.exit()` defined? What's your question?

Comment: send mail is the function written in the script,which send the mail to the user, when fatal error occurs...System.error is typing mistake...its actually sys.exit()...i want whnever "fatal error occurs" it come out and pass the exit value to the batch file

Comment: Did you read [the docs of sys.exit()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.exit)?

Comment: Hi Janne yes i red the same...but not useful

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
sys.exit(1)
```

to have the Python script end with an error. But, as the `sys.exit` [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html) documentation states, this might not work on Windows (the doc speaks of "shells and the like").

I infer you are using Windows because you speak of "batch files". Maybe you have to do Windows-Batch-File-Magic and rephrase a question fo be about Windows rather then Python then.